# Text in list doesn't align properly with the rest of list because it is pushed under ::before pseudo element

Tags: html, css, list, alignment

So I wanted to make a list with checkmarks instead of bullet points.
Therefore I decided to make a ::before pseudo-element like this:

```
ul{ list-style-type: none;}

li::before{
content: "\2713";
font-size: 1.2rem;
margin: 0 4px;}
```

While this actually works pretty well, I have the problem that once the text of the li wraps and goes on a new line, it won't align with the rest of the text (list) anymore, but would rather go on the next line under the checkmark (::before element).

Now, I already tried things like position: absolute; but that doesn't work either since the ::before element is taken out of the flow and will just go above the text of the list item.
I have also tried text-indent on the li but all of this won't work.
Also, since it is a ::before element and list-style-type is set to none; list-style-position: outside; won't work either.

So what do I have to do so that the text of my list item will align with the list once it wraps on a new line and doesn't go under the ::before ?

Answer (score 2):

All you need to do is set the `position` of the `::before` pseudo-element to `absolute` as you did before. However, make sure to set the `position` of the `li` elements to `relative` as well, so that any changes to the `position` of the `::before` pseudo-elements become relative to their `li`. Finally, adjust the `top` and `left` values of the pseudo-element the way you want. Here is a working example.

```css
ul {
  list-style: none;
}

li {
  position: relative;
}

li::before {
  content: "\2713";
  position: absolute;
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  top: -5px;
  left: -20px;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</li>
  <li>Ut sapien sapien, porttitor ac tellus sed</li>
  <li>ullamcorper tempor orci</li>
  <li>Nulla maximus nibh malesuada sem commodo molestie</li>
</ul>
```